# Places you can reference self in Python classes (Django model)?

Tags: python, django, self

I have a model that looks like something like the following:

```py
class Location:
    related_q: Q
    def whatever(self):
        return SomeModel.objects.filter(related_q)

class Place(models.Model, Location):
    attr1 = models.CharField…
    …
    related_q = Q(some_field__something_else=self)
```

Is there some way to make code like this that actually works?  This exact code won't run because `self` is not actually defined when `related_q` is declared.

The options I'm thinking of are just making `whatever` abstract in `Location` and defining it in the subclasses or making `related_q` a string and altering the code to be along the lines of the following:

```py
class Location:
    related_q: Q
    def whatever(self):
        return SomeModel.objects.filter(related_q=self)

class Place(models.Model, Location):
    attr1 = models.CharField…
    …
    related_q = "some_field__something_else"
```

However, this doesn't work because `related_q` here is treated as the literal name of the kwarg and not as the name of the string containing the kwarg.

Answer (score 0):

class variables can also be accessed using self

```
class Location:
    related_q: Q
    def whatever(self):
        return SomeModel.objects.filter(self.related_q)
```

or you can refrence it directly using class name

```
class Location:
    related_q: Q
    def whatever(self):
        return SomeModel.objects.filter(Location.related_q)
```